# package <name> does not exist error

Tags: java

I have the following sample code from a book in their respective files, each file having the same name as the interface or class defined in it:

`Logger.java`

```
package logging;

public interface Logger
{
   boolean connect();
   boolean disconnect();
   boolean log(String msg);
}
```

`LoggerFactory.java`

```
package logging;

public abstract class LoggerFactory
{
   public final static int CONSOLE = 0;
   public final static int FILE = 1;

   public static Logger newLogger(int dstType, String... dstName)
   {
      switch (dstType)
      {
         case CONSOLE: return new Console(dstName.length == 0 ? null : dstName[0]);
         case FILE   : return new File(dstName.length == 0 ? null : dstName[0]);
         default     : return null;
      }
   }
}
```

`Console.java`

```
package logging;

class Console implements Logger
{
   private String dstName;

   Console(String dstName)
   {
      this.dstName = dstName;
   }

   @Override
   public boolean connect()
   {
      return true;
   }

   @Override
   public boolean disconnect()
   {
      return true;
   }

   @Override
   public boolean log(String msg)
   {
      System.out.println(msg);
      return true;
   }
}
```

`File.java`

```
package logging;

class File implements Logger
{
   private String dstName;

   File(String dstName)
   {
      this.dstName = dstName;
   }

   @Override
   public boolean connect()
   {
      if (dstName == null)
         return false;
      System.out.println("opening file " + dstName);
      return true;
   }

   @Override
   public boolean disconnect()
   {
      if (dstName == null)
         return false;
      System.out.println("closing file " + dstName);
      return true;
   }

   @Override
   public boolean log(String msg)
   {
      if (dstName == null)
         return false;
      System.out.println("writing "+msg+" to file " + dstName);
      return true;
   }
}
```

`TestLogger.java`

```
// package logging;

import logging.Logger;
import logging.LoggerFactory;

public class TestLogger
{
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
      Logger logger = LoggerFactory.newLogger(LoggerFactory.CONSOLE);
      if (logger.connect())
      {
         logger.log("test message #1");
         logger.disconnect();
      }
      else
         System.out.println("cannot connect to console-based logger");
      logger = LoggerFactory.newLogger(LoggerFactory.FILE, "x.txt");
      if (logger.connect())
      {
         logger.log("test message #2");
         logger.disconnect();
      }
      else
         System.out.println("cannot connect to file-based logger");
      logger = LoggerFactory.newLogger(LoggerFactory.FILE);
      if (logger.connect())
      {
         logger.log("test message #3");
         logger.disconnect();
      }
      else
         System.out.println("cannot connect to file-based logger");
   }
}
```

All of these files are inside a folder called `logger`. The book says that executing `javac TestLogger.java` should find and compile all the necessary class files in the `logger` directory, but I get an error

```
TestLogger.java:3: error: package logging does not exist
import logging.Logger;
              ^
```

followed by other errors mainly related to not being able to find the `logging` package. Why isn't this program compiling? I have tried creating CLASSPATH system variable that points to the parent folder of `logging` as well as trying
`javac -classpath "parent_folder_of_logging" TestLogger.java` but nothing is working. What is wrong here and how do I fix it?

Comment: `TestLogger` should *not* be in the `logging` directory unless it's declared to be in package `logging`. Your directory structure should make your package structure, basically - then compile from the root directory as Ernesto says.

Comment: ah ok I see. I made a mistake in the location of TestLogger. But again, if I put the line `package logger` in the TestLogger.java file as well, why doesn't it still compile?

Comment: Because then you need to compile it from the *parent* directory as per Ernesto's answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to parent folder of logging and execute:

```
 javac logging/TestLogger.java
```

For execute in the same folder do

```
 java logging.TestLogger
```

Comment: thank you, this works. But the book says to execute just `javac TestLogger.java` and it should do the rest. Why isn't is working on my case?

Comment: @user13267: If `TestLogger` isn't in the `logging` package (the package directive is commented out) then it should be in just the root directory, with `logging` *beneath* it.

Comment: Because a filename must follow the directory structure. In the book, you were compiling the file from the same directory but whenever there is a package strucutre, you should compile from the root of package structure

Comment: you can find a good tutorial for the same here http://www.thejavageek.com/2013/07/21/using-javac-and-java-commands-to-compile-and-launch-java-programs/

Comment: I can see now where I made the mistake, but even then, uncommenting the `package logger` line in `TestLogger.java` doesn't compile. Why is that?

Answer (score 1):

Put all the files in the logger directory

Execute from outside the logger directory

```
javac logging/TestLogger.java
```

Answer (score 1):

Class TestLogger must be in other package!

Answer (score 0):

Basically you need to put all the files in directory with name logging and then run the application from outside the directory and with the

```
javac -cp classpath classname

java -cp classpath packagename.classname
```

Comment: The problem is *compiling* - we need to help the OP with that before we get to *running*.